# Good way of firing an event at a particular time of day?

Tags: c#, events

I have an app that needs to fire off a couple of events at certain times during the day - the times are all defined by the users. I can think of a couple of ways of doing it but none of them sit too well. The timing doesn't have to be of a particularly high resolution - a minute or so each way is fine.

My ideas :

1. When the app starts up read all the times and start timers off that will Tick at the appropriate time
2. Start a timer off that'll check every minute or so for 'current events'

tia for any better solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Store/index the events sorted by when they next need attention. This could be in memory or not according to how many there are, how often you make changes, etc. If all of your events fire once a day, this list is basically a circular buffer which only changes when users change their events.
- Start a timer which will 'tick' at the time of the event at the head of the list. Round up to the next minute if you like.
- When the timer fires, process all events which are now in the past [edit - and which haven't already been processed], re-insert them into the list if necessary (i.e. if you don't have the "circular buffer" optimisation), and set a new timer.

Obviously, when you change the set of events, or change the time for an existing event, then you may need to reset the timer to make it fire earlier. There's usually no point resetting it to fire later - you may as well just let it go off and do nothing. And if you put an upper limit of one minute on how long the timer can run (or just have a 1 minute recurring timer), then you can get within 1-minute accuracy without ever resetting. This is basically your option 2.

Arguably you should use an existing framework rather than rolling your own, but I don't know C# so I have no idea what's available. I'm generally a bit wary of the idea of setting squillions of timers, because some environments don't support that (or don't support it well). Hence this scheme, which requires only one. I don't know whether C# has any problems in that respect, but this scheme can easily be arranged to use O(1) RAM if necessary, which can't be beat.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). It is a scheduler framework (originally for Java).

Comment: We use Quartz on our team for Java. I highly recommend it. It is released under the Apache 2.0 license (free to use, give credit where due)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a classic case for a Windows Service.  I think there is a Windows Service project type in VS2005/2008.  The service coupled with a simple database and a front-end application to allow users to set the trigger times would be all you need.

If it won't change very often, Scheduled Tasks is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a few programs along these lines.

I suggest #2.  All you need to to is keep a list of times that events are "due" at, and every X amount of time (depending on your resolution) check your list for "now" events.  You can pick up some optimization if you can guarantee the list is sorted, and that each event on the list is due exactly once.  Otherwise, if you have recurring events, you have to make sure you cover your window.  What I mean is, if you have an event that is due at 11:30 am, and you're checking every seconds, then it's possible that you could check at 11:29:59, and then not again until 11:31:01, due to the inprecision of the CPU time-slices.  So you'll need to be sure that one of those checks (11:29 or 11:31) still picks up the 11:30 hit, and that ONLY one of them does (i.e., you don't run at both 11:29 and 11:31).

The advantage this approach has over checking only on times you know to be on your list is that allows your list to be modified by 3rd parties without your knowledge, and your event handler will continue to 'just work'.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would likely be to use Windows scheduler.

Otherwise you need to use one of the Timer classes, calculating how long until the first event. This approach, unlike the scheduler, allows new events to be found by the running process (and, possibly, resetting the timer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with #1 is that the number of milliseconds before an event may be too large to store in the Timer's interval, and as the number of events increase, your number of timers could get unweildly.

I dont see anything wrong with #2, but I would opt for a background worker or a thread.