# PopUp window on a specific time in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

How can I create and show a popup window at a specific time in WPF?
What I mean how to display the window on the side of system tray.

Comment: This shouldn't be voted down because it doesn't have enough clarity!  Give the guy a chance...

Comment: Is there any option for creating a popup window in wpf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a timer if you're trying to make the thing popup in a certain number of hours/seconds/minutes (or work out how many hours/seconds/minutes are left until your specific time comes around).

```
private System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer popupTimer;

// Whatever is going to start the timer - I've used a click event
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    popupTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

    // Work out interval as time you want to popup - current time
    popupTimer.Interval = specificTime - DateTime.Now;
    popupTimer.IsEnabled = true;
    popupTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(popupTimer_Tick);
}

void popupTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    popupTimer.IsEnabled = false;
    // Show popup
    // ......
}
```

---

Ok, so you also want to know how to do a notifier popup type thing, which maybe this article in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_TaskbarNotifier.aspx?display=Print) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725917/good-way-of-firing-an-event-at-a-particular-time-of-day) for firing an event at a set time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).