# Timer class and C#

Tags: c#

I have a program written in C#. I want the Timer class to run a function at a specific time.

E.g : run function X at 20:00 PM

How can I do that using the Timer class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Timer Tick event to check (Set the tick to a suitable value) then in the tick event:

```
DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;

if(Now.Hours == DateTimeCallX.Hours 
 && Now.Minutes == DateTimeCallX.Minutes 
 && xHasRan == false)
  {
  x();
  xHasRan = true;
  }
```

DateTimeCallX being a DateTime object set to 20:00.
xHasRan is a boolean stating whether the function has been called, this will be initially set to false and set to true after x has been called so that if the timer tick runs again in the same minute then it won't run the function again.

Comment: the small issue with this solution is that if timer does not run in minute intervals you would not execute x().  Maybe thing about using >= instead of ==

Answer (score 4):

[Good way of firing an event at a particular time of day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725917/good-way-of-firing-an-event-at-a-particular-time-of-day)

Answer (score 2):

When the timer fires, check the time and whether the function has run that day. If the time is after 20:00 and the function hasn't been called, call it. Otherwise, exit and wait for the next event.

Also, keep in mind that the forms timer and System.Threading.Timer work slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to calculate the number of milliseconds until 20:00 PM or use a scheduler like [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score -1):

Set the timer to run a method that checks what time it is, and run your code if the desired time has past, or goes back to sleep for FEW MILLISECONDS IF IT HAS NOT.

Comment: Note that you also need to check whether the code has ran already. This can be done by changing the desired run-time or by keeping a timestamp when the last run was performed. Also I think that sleeping a few milliseconds and checking again is not a very good thing for you performance (checking the time takes resources, not much, but it takes them). Depending on the situation you should use a longer sleep period (for example: if it isn't a problem that the process runs 5 minutes later pick a interval of 5 minutes).

Comment: @Gertjan,  No, you don't... If the timer detects that the time has past, it "runs the code", it does not reset itself to wake up again...  it "runs the code" and terminates.